# inserting xml to sql server 12 using java

Tags: java, sql-server, xml

Following is my XML, that I have to store in SQL server db. that table has 2 columns. email and Xml.

XML:

```
<Users>
<user>
<FN>a</FN>
<LN>b</LN>
<ph>123</ph>
<email>abc</email>
</user>
<user>
<FN>c</FN>
<LN>d</LN>
<ph>456</ph>
<email>def</email>
</user>
<user>
<FN>r</FN>
<LN>p</LN>
<ph>321</ph>
<email>xyz</email>
</user>
</Users>
```

I split the XML using the following code.

public class XmlSplit {

```
public static void xmlSplit(File file) throws Exception  {
    XMLInputFactory if = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader sr = if.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(file));
    sr.nextTag(); // Advance to statements element

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
    int counter = 1;
    while(sr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
       counter++;
        File file2 = new File(counter + ".xml");
        System.out.println(file2);
        t.transform(new StAXSource(sr), new StreamResult(file2));
    }
}

}
```

Now Instead of writing the split xmls into files, Can I create SQLXML objects directly or using a loop? And also I have to get email from the corresponding xml fragment and store it in a separate column. (Sometimes I don't have to split xml as there will be only 1 user and in other cases there will be 5-10 users in 1 xml file). (These xmls, I got as Strings in response to a web Service call and I have written these Strings into files).

Comment: What do you mean "SQLXML" objects? SQL Server has an XML data type to and from which you can read. You can store down entire documents or XML fragments, and also enforce an XSD if you like.

Comment: Yes.. To store that xml in xml datatype column, we don't have to use     preparedstatement.setSQLXML (1,xmlObject)? Is there any other way to store xml?